# Как изменить данные в JSON файле с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, json

Есть JSON файл вида: `{"name" : "value1"}` .

С помощью PHP я достаю значение `value1`, каким-то образом изменяю (не суть важно) и хочу уже измененное значение `value1_new` запихнуть в JSON так, чтобы получился файл вида: `{"name" : "value1_new"}`.

То есть если было `{"name" : "Ivan"}`, чтоб стало `{"name" : "Vasiliy"}` после моих манипуляций.

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('./json_file.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$name = $json['name'];
// манипуляции с $name
// ...
// Например, было $name="Ivan", стало $name="Vasiliy"
// и тут нужно в JSON закинуть уже измененный $name
```

Я что-то никак не пойму, как это сделать, так что прошу помощи у соображающих коллег))

Comment: Вероятно после декодирования - json_decode, вам нужно изменить сначала $json['name'] = "Vasiluy", а после закодировать json_encode($json) и переписать файл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('./json_file.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$json['name'] = 'Vasiluy';

$newJsonString = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents('./json_file.json', $newJsonString);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что я и искал)

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"key0":"value0","key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}';
$items = json_decode($json, true);
$items['key1'] = 'new value';
$json = json_encode($items);

print_r($json); // {"key0":"value0","key1":"new value","key2":"value2"}
```

Comment: json_encode(); разве перезаписывает данные в самом файле?

Comment: он дает вам json строку, которую уже можете через file_put_contents записать в файл

Comment: Понял, спасибо)